# Command not detected -> roscd: command not found

Tags: ros

Many commands like **roscd, rosls, roslaunch** are not working. Errors are thrown as :-
roscd: command not found

What may be the reasons behind this?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that your **setup.bash** hasn't been sourced in a terminal window.

Try executing this command:

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
```

If that won't work try following the steps on site bellow, as they are beautifully explained on how to install ROS on Ubuntu.

http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu#groovy.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup

Answer (score 0):

you need to setup you environment and add variables to your bash
just use the following commands..

```
echo "source 'your setup.bash file path'" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```